# Case statement in where clause and els do nothing

Tags: sql

please check  below query

```
DECLARE @status varchar(1)
DECLARE @code varchar(50)

Set @status = '0'

select id,code from MasterTable where 
('07/31/2012' between  StartDate and EndDate) and 
Case when @status = '0' and Status=@status then 1 end = 1
```

this query works for me, but not work for `@Status=1`

I need query like

```
if @Status = '0'
    select id,code from MasterTable where 
   ('07/31/2012' between  StartDate and EndDate) and Status = @Status
   if @code <> '0' 
        select id,code from MasterTable where 
        ('07/31/2012' between  StartDate and EndDate) and Status = @Status and code =@code
else
     select id,code from MasterTable where 
   ('07/31/2012' between  StartDate and EndDate) 
      if @code <> '0' 
        select id,code from MasterTable where 
        ('07/31/2012' between  StartDate and EndDate) and Status = @Status and code =@code
```

How can I achieve this using case when statement ?

Comment: Which SQL? SQL Server , MySQL etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the query by rephrasing it slightly:

```
select  id,code 
from    MasterTable 
where   '07/31/2012' between  StartDate and EndDate)
        and (@status <> '0' or Status = @status)
```

Comment: @Andomar , what happend f there are more than one where criteria , please check my updated question

Comment: You can add many lines like `(@a <> '0' or col1 = @a) and (@b <> '0' or col2 = @b) and ...`

Comment: @Andomar Can you please update your answer with this particular updated question? I have same problem. I understand it for single condition but confused in multiple (or nested) condition.

Comment: @Andomar Is there any official documentation (link) for `WHERE` conditions with nested conditions?